# Compare rows and columns to add result in new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, exception

I've need to compare data in diferents columns and row and I've a complex for and if python code. I'm thinking for a bether solution but I not found any more with my limited python knowhow.

I need to compare the "Open" value with previous row "Close" and if the diference is more than X value, 3 for this example I need to add a GapUp or GapDown text in "Gap" column.

I've this code and I need to add the first "df["Gap"] = None" line to solve the for exception error:

Any ideas to make it more simple and functionally?

```
df["Gap"] = None
N = 3
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df['Open'][i] > df['Close'][i-1] and df['Open'][i] - df['Close'][i-1] > N:
        df['Gap'][i] = 'GapUp'
    elif df['Open'][i] < df['Close'][i-1] and df['Close'][i-1] - df['Open'][i] > N:
        df['Gap'][i] = 'GapDown'
    else:
        df['Gap'][i] = None
```

| Date | Open | Close | Gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-17 | 178,90 | 184,36 | NaN |
| 2018-01-18 | 187,36 | 192,14 | GapUp |
| 2018-01-19 | 184,27 | 180,24 | GapDown |
| 2018-01-20 | 181,17 | 182,45 | NaN |
| 2018-01-21 | 183,14 | 187,47 | NaN |
| 2018-01-22 | 188,14 | 191,78 | NaN |
| 2018-01-23 | 205,41 | 209,17 | GapUp |
| 2018-01-24 | 211,02 | 215,27 | NaN |
| 2018-01-25 | 219,89 | 223,17 | GapUp |
| 2018-01-26 | 223,08 | 219,21 | NaN |
| 2018-01-27 | 212,32 | 206,21 | GapDown |
| 2018-01-28 | 205,14 | 203,12 | NaN |
| 2018-01-29 | 204,32 | 201,93 | NaN |
| 2018-01-30 | 199,45 | 195,15 | NaN |
| 2018-01-31 | 191,23 | 189,16 | GapDown |
| 2018-02-01 | 188,42 | 184,67 | NaN |
| 2018-02-02 | 183,12 | 186,74 | NaN |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to create a temporary column with the Previous Close then use a function to generate the Gap indicator:

```
def func(open, close):
    gap = open - close
    if gap >= 3.0:
        return 'GapUp'
    elif gap <= -3.0:
        return 'GapDown'
    else:
        return None
    
df['PrevClose'] = df['Close'].shift(1)
df['Gap'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['Open'], x['PrevClose']), axis = 1)
df.drop(['PrevClose'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Using your idea I find other other solution and not need the if conditions I think. 
    <code>df['PrevClose'] = df['Close'].shift(1)df.loc[df['Open'] - df['PrevClose'] > 3,'Gap'] = 'GapUp'
    df.loc[df['PrevClose'] - df['Open'] > 3,'Gap'] = 'GapDown'
    df.drop(['PrevClose'], axis = 1, inplace = True)<code>